# Disable Keyboard globally for a WPF Window

Tags: c#, wpf, events, .net-4.0

I need to disable Keyboard Input for all UI elements except one or 2 exceptions.

Thing is, I need the arrow keys for controlling so I added a KeyEventHandler on the MainWindow  level and added another for UI Elements like Tab Items, Textbox so that they ignore the Input when they got the focus.
I ended up with a pretty buggie control. I still can browse e.g. thru tab items, the control event sometimes doesn't fire. I need a more reliable way to do this..

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: You could try to catch each KeyDown event and set e.Handled = true; at each UserControl you want to ignore the Keyboard.

Comment: Thats what I tried, but that leads to the buggy behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arrow keys are not considered input keys by default. Therefore they still scroll through the controls on the window. To change this behavior you can subscribe to the `PreviewKeyDown` event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewkeydown.aspx) and set `PreviewKeyDownEventArgs.IsInputKey = true;`, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.previewkeydowneventargs.isinputkey.aspx. Then the arrow keys will also invoke other key event handlers as `KeyDown`.